# Magento2 auto search suggestion display issue

Tags: search, search-result

Magento2 auto suggestion search result showing special characters any solution?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUD6D.png

Comment: use escapeQuotes in your autosuggestion file

Comment: @ParulThakkar : it's js issue.